# check which node user navigated from websitemap asp.net

Tags: sitemap

Here's is the scenario .

I have a Website.Map with the following nodes as part of it .

```
<siteMapNode title="Self" url="" description="" roles="STF,FAC">
<siteMapNode title="My Schedule" url="" description="~/schedule.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="My Report" url="" description="~/report.aspx" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode title="Supervisor" url="" roles="SUP">
<siteMapNode title=" Manage Schedule" url="" description="~/schedule.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="Send Notification" url="" description="~/notification.aspx" />
</siteMapNode>
```

In my website, I have an aspx page called schedule.aspx which I would use to list schedule.I could navigate to this page from

a)   Self-> My Schedule  in website map menu
or
b)  Supervisor - > Manage Schedules in website map menu .

1) When I navigate to schedule page from  Self - > My Schedule , the schedule page has to show my( user's  ) schedule

or

2) When I navigate to schedule page from  Supervisor - > Manage Schedule , the schedule page has to show all my subordinates  ( those whom User supervises ) schedules.

So in the pageload event of  schedule.aspx , I would like to check where the user is coming from whether from Self or from Supervisor.

Is there any way I could achieve this ?